# JavaScript / jQuery code doesn't add value to input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to create a kind of "keygenerator" for my project, so I'm using this code in a script inside of a Bootstrap project:

```
 var keyWA = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); 
  var keyA = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); 

  $("#buttonWA").click(function(){
    if (keyWA == 1) {
      $("input[name=inputWA]").val(2405-3443-9893-5346);
   } else {
      $("input[name=inputWA]").val(2350-8496-2225-4682);
  });
```

But it's not working. It does not put anything on the input. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not sure why it's not posting to your input, can you post your HTML for the button and the inputs? Also, you should quote those values, or else you're performing a math operation, 2405 minus 3443 minus 9893 minus 5346 for a total of -16277

Comment: The most probable reason it wouldn't put *anything* in the specified input is because your input selector is wrong, or because the DOM element doesn't exist yet. Add `console.log($("input[name=inputWA]").length)` in there to see if it's greater than zero.

Comment: `2350-8496-2225-4682`... are you doing math here or is that supposed to be a string? You're also missing a closing brace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Put single quotes in .val() because it is not a pure integer/float

```
$('input[name="inputWA"]').val('2350-8496-2225-4682');
```

also check out how I quoted $('input[name="inputWA"]')

**EDIT:**

```
$( ' input[name=   " inputWA      " ]        ' )
// ^single         ^double        ^double    ^single
```

Comment: This should still add a value, just not the desired one.

Comment: I tried that but still nothing. I don't know what is happening ._.

Comment: @Zox09 You should definitely update your post with HTML code as well. A JSfiddle showing that it is broken would be preferable

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gk4GB)
Here it's, of course all the images are not displaying and some of the code it's not finished yet, but you can see it there.

Comment: should should put your jQuery include directly below the <title>zox simz</title><script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: It works perfectly with that button, but when I try to put that code in my web with a Bootstrap button it does not work. Why is that happening?

Comment: It does work, notice on the left-hand side I have added jQuery 1.x (edge) in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gk4GB/2/

Comment: Yeah, and still nothing. This is so weird o.o

Comment: What do you mean nothing? I click the Blue button and the number changes

Comment: Okay, I didn't see your second fiddle. I feel so stupid right now, it works perfectly now. Thank you for everything! :D

Answer (score 1):

You missed a bracket

```
$("#buttonWA").click(function(){
    if (keyWA == 1) {
        $("input[name=inputWA]").val(2405-3443-9893-5346);
    } else {
        $("input[name=inputWA]").val(2350-8496-2225-4682);
    } //<-- this one is missing
});
```

Also, wrap `2405-3443-9893-5346` in quotes like `'2405-3443-9893-5346'`.